# CASE or IF in AND statement

Tags: sql, if-statement, parameters, case

I've got a query with a bunch of AND statements. Now when a variable is set, I want to use a specific AND statement. But when it's empty or NULL I don't want that statement. I've found some things with IF and CASE but I can't get it done :(

I Want something like this

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE [Statement1]

IF @Location IS NOT NULL OR <> ''
BEGIN
    AND [SBC Live 2$Sales Shipment Line].[Location _ Sector No_] = @Location
END
```

Maybe someone can help me?

Thnanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE [Statement1] AND (ISNULL(@Location,'') = '' OR [SBC Live 2$Sales Shipment Line].[Location _ Sector No_] = @Location)
```

So in the end, either @Location is null/blank, or it matches the [SBC Live 2$Sales Shipment Line].[Location _ Sector No_]

Note:  In your pseudo-code, you have OR in the IF check, but based off what you wrote previously, I assume you're looking for AND there.

Comment: Thanks! I will review it tommorow and come back with feedback :)